# asp.NET Drop Down List within a Grid View - Getting the selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a status drop down list which I am using within a grid view, the users can select a list item they want when editing a row within the grid view. The problem is that the current implementation is not retrieving the selected value, but is only retrieving the default/loaded value.

This is the defination of the grid view:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="applicationGrid" runat="server"  Width="95%"
        AutoGenerateEditButton="True" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        ShowFooter="True"
        CellSpacing="10" 
        HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" 
        ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
        OnRowUpdating="applicationGrid_RowUpdating" 
        OnRowEditing="applicationGrid_RowEditing" 
        OnRowCancelingEdit="applicationGrid_RowCancelingEdit"
        AutoPostBack="true" >
```

And this is the defination of the Column where the dropdown list will appear on edit:

```
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                <ItemTemplate>   
                    <asp:Label ID="StatusDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("STATUS_DESCRIPTION") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="StatusDescriptionList" runat="server" DataTextField="status_description"
                            DataValueField="application_status_code" OnLoad="DropDownLoadEdit">
                       <asp:ListItem Text="Status:" Value="default"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

This is the code behind which is handling the update scenario:

```
    protected void applicationGrid_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = applicationGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        applicationGrid.EditIndex = -1;

        Label applicationCodeLabel = row.FindControl("AppID") as Label;
        TextBox applicationNameTextBox = row.FindControl("AppNameEdit") as TextBox;
        TextBox applicationURLTextBox = row.FindControl("AppURLEdit") as TextBox;
        DropDownList applicationStatusDropDownList = row.FindControl("StatusDescriptionList") as DropDownList;

        int applicationCode = Convert.ToInt32(applicationCodeLabel.Text);
        string applicationName = applicationNameTextBox.Text;
        string applicationURL = applicationURLTextBox.Text;
        int applicationStatus = Convert.ToInt32(applicationStatusDropDownList.SelectedValue.ToString());
        //string applicationStatus2 = applicationStatusDropDownList.SelectedItem.Value;
        //string applicationStatus3 = applicationStatusDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text;

        application.UpdateApplication(applicationCode, applicationName, applicationURL);
        PopulateApplications();
    }
```

All is working, but the selected value is not the one which the is loaded and not the one which the user selects. Therefore the problem is getting the selected value from the list. What needs to be changed, and why?

```
        protected void applicationGrid_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = applicationGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        applicationGrid.EditIndex = -1;

        Label applicationCodeLabel = row.FindControl("AppID") as Label;
        TextBox applicationNameTextBox = row.FindControl("AppNameEdit") as TextBox;
        TextBox applicationURLTextBox = row.FindControl("AppURLEdit") as TextBox;
        DropDownList applicationStatusDropDownList = row.FindControl("StatusDescriptionList") as DropDownList;

        int applicationCode = Convert.ToInt32(applicationCodeLabel.Text);
        string applicationName = applicationNameTextBox.Text;
        string applicationURL = applicationURLTextBox.Text;
        int applicationStatus = Convert.ToInt32(applicationStatusDropDownList.SelectedValue.ToString());
        //string applicationStatus2 = applicationStatusDropDownList.SelectedItem.Value;
        //string applicationStatus3 = applicationStatusDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text;

        application.UpdateApplication(applicationCode, applicationName, applicationURL);
        PopulateApplications();
    }
```

EDIT: Adding my Populate Methods:

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            try
            {
                PopulateApplications();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                throw exception;
            }
        }
    }

    private void PopulateApplications()
    {
        DataTable reader = application.GetApplicationList();
        applicationGrid.DataSource = reader;
        applicationGrid.DataBind();
        applicationGrid.AllowSorting = true;
    }

    protected void DropDownLoadEdit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
            DataTable statusTable = application.GetStatusList();

            DropDownList dropdown = sender as DropDownList;
            dropdown.DataSource = statusTable;
            dropdown.DataTextField = "status_description";
            dropdown.DataValueField = "application_status_code";
            dropdown.DataBind()
    }
```

Update #2: I am trying to fill up a static variable in the class which is for the selected index. This will then be used when update is pressed. However, this is still getting the original value of the drop down list and not the selected one.

This is the method:

```
    protected void StatusDescriptionList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
        selectedValue = Convert.ToInt32(ddl.SelectedValue.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging to see what value is selected if any at this point: DropDownList applicationStatusDropDownList = row.FindControl("StatusDescriptionList") as DropDownList;

Comment: @Gaz Winter - Yes, the Value is always 1, which is the default one. When I select the value which should be 2, it is still 1. Therefore, not detecting a change in the selection within the drop down list.

Comment: <asp:DropDownList ID="StatusDescriptionList" runat="server" DataTextField="status_description"
                            DataValueField="application_status_code" OnLoad="DropDownLoadEdit" AutoPostBack="True">

Comment: @MMK - When I set that to AutoPostBack="true" it refreshes the page and loads the old value back. Is there another step to this?

Comment: are you using the event of SelectedIndexChanged event to select a value?

Comment: @MMK I can't manage to get the selected index from the dropdown list on that event. I have added the method, but can't understand how to handle it.

Comment: protected void ddlList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Find the DropDownList Control here
        int intId = Convert.ToInt32(NameofDDLhere.SelectedValue);

    }

Comment: @MMK - Yes I did this now:             DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
            selectedValue = Convert.ToInt32(ddl.SelectedValue.ToString()); but I still have a problem because it is still not getting the selected value, but the value which was loaded.

Comment: what happen when you fire the event?

Comment: My logic was, that when a dropdown list is changed, store it as a static variable, and then update it when update is pressed. However, When the update is pressed, it is still getting the default values which were retrieved when populating.

Comment: @MMK Updated Code, look at the final update to understand my reasoning

Comment: please bind the Dropdown list in   if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            try
            {   // BIND Your Drop Down list here
                PopulateApplications();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                throw exception;
            }
        }

Comment: @MMK - how can I? if that method is automatically called when the dropdownlist is called (when EDIT is pressed)

Comment: @Ryan- I can't see where you are binding the dropdown's SelectedIndexChanged to StatusDescriptionList_SelectedIndexChanged method. Where did you do this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you repopulating the list in `DropDownLoadEdit`, regardless of whether the transition is a postback or not? If so, the list will be repopulated before its value is read, and set to the default before your method has a chance to read the value.

Comment: What about "DropDownLoadEdit"?

Comment: What happens if you add a if (!IsPostBack) into the Dropdownloadedit?

Comment: @pdoluska - If I do that, it doesn't even populate the dropdown lists.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be of the post back.

Once the item is selected from the drop down the page get post back the value you selected get vanished.

To over come this issue. Bind the drop down list inside page is post back or else make use of a Ajax update panel.

Comment: @Guarav Adding such code will not even populate the list when EDIT is pressed, is this what you meant?
       protected void DropDownLoadEdit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                DataTable statusTable = application.GetStatusList();

                DropDownList dropdown = sender as DropDownList;
                dropdown.DataSource = statusTable;
                dropdown.DataTextField = "status_description";
                dropdown.DataValueField = "application_status_code";
                dropdown.DataBind();
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

@Ryan, Have you done this
'
AutopostBack="True"

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="StatusDescriptionList" runat="server" AutopostBack="True" DataTextField="status_description"
                            DataValueField="application_status_code" OnLoad="DropDownLoadEdit">
                       <asp:ListItem Text="Status:" Value="default"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="StatusDescriptionList" runat="server" DataTextField="status_description"
                        DataValueField="application_status_code" SelectedValue="application_status_code" AutopostBack="True" OnLoad="DropDownLoadEdit">
                   <asp:ListItem Text="Status:" Value="default"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
```